# Starting play server with activator throw an application.conf not found error

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, sbt-native-packager

I have a very strange problem.

I'm creating a server with play 2.3. when I launch it with `activator run`, it works perfectly. But if I use `activator start` to launch the server in deployement mode, I'm getting an IOException: file not found for application.conf.

```
Configuration error: Configuration error[application: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties]
```

When I run `activator windows:packageBin` it give me a warning about evicted library :

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:0.7.4 -> 1.0.3
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

The strange thing is that it have been working few month ago...

Here is my build.sbt file :

```
name := """IdTabDriver"""
version := "1.0.0.1"

name in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

//packageSummary in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

//packageDescription in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

maintainer in Windows := "Access France"

organization := "Access France"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.10",
  "org.rxtx" % "rxtxcomm" % "2.0-7pre1"
)
```

And my plugin.sbt file :

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.3")
```

EDIT : I have use the `-Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf` option to solve the previous exception, but I get a new one

```
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot initialize the custom Global object (controllers.Global) (perhaps it's a wrong reference?)]
```

Comment: What happens if you tell activator to use this configuration file explicitly like with `-Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf`?

Comment: @Kris Edited the question with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is well known [#499](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/499), [#554](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/554) and on [play #4242](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4242).

Playframework 2.3.x doesn't use AutoPlugins all the way through. This causes strange issues when you mix AutoPlugins (sbt-native-packager 1.0.3) and non-AutoPlugin builds (like play 2.3.x).

Furthermore you are using the **JavaAppPackaging** archetype, but play already enables the **JavaServerAppPackaging** archetype. This may also cause some strange behaviors like yours.

So the solution would be

- upgrade play 2.3.x to 2.4.x
- OR downgrade sbt-native-packager to 0.8.x

You may also look at [our docs for play](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/topics/play.html)

Comment: Hum I was afraid of that kind of problem... I can't upgrade to play 2.4 because I haven't java 8... And I don't know if you can make a windows installer with sbt-native-packager 0.8 ?

Comment: windows installer should be possible with 0.8.0 as well.

Comment: But I don't know how to custom the config file ? It seems to not export added files (certificates)

Comment: The documentation can be found here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/windows.html